# Linq to check if all value from another list exist

Tags: c#, linq, list

I have list of values as below

List 1

```
--
Id Country market

1   AU       2

2   NZ       2

3   GB       3

4   GG       3
```

I have another list which is as below

### List 2

```
location country

2         AU

2         NZ

3         GB

3         IR
```

I would like to pull the location from list 2 where country satisfies in List 1 and by market. which means I need to pull "2" as location from List 2 for market = 2 because location 2 satisfy the values ( which are AU and NZ) whereas location 3 failed the validation because not all the countries (from list 1) are in list 2.

I would like to know if we can write this in LINQ statement. I can write using loop to find out each matching criteria but I am thinking of easier and better way of writing this in LINQ.

Comment: http://www.sqltolinq.com

Comment: put your code in question please.

Answer (score 2):

If you only interested in knowing all `List1` entries exists in `List2` then you could do this.

```
bool allexist = list1.All(l=> list2.Any(x=> x.location == l.market && x.Country == l.Country));
```

or, if you would like to know all `List1` entries exists in `List2` then this

```
var existsinBoth = list1.Where(l=> list2.Any(x=> x.location == l.market && x.Country == l.Country));
```